# Scala method to convert generic Collection

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How can I create a method that takes a generic Collection `M[A]` and a function from `A` to `B` and returns a Collection `M[B]`, using the map method?

Something like:
`def convert[A, M[X] <: Traversable[X], B](in: M[A], f: A => B): M[B] = 
in.map(f)`

The method above fails to compile with: `type mismatch; found : Traversable[B] required: M[B]`. Since the static type of `Traversable[A].map(f: A => B)` is `Traversable[B]` as pointed by [Oleg Pyzhcov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2758343/oleg-pyzhcov)

Note: The purpose of this method is not just mapping the collection, this is just a simplification.

Comment: Whats wrong with method you posted in question?

Comment: The method fails to compile:
type mismatch;
 found   : Traversable[B]
 required: M[B]

Comment: Please include it in your question. It will simplify search in future.

Comment: To completely understand the answer for this question provided below I had to read this article http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html which might be useful for others who will face similar tasks in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full signature of `map` is

```
def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

So you need to provide that `CanBuildFrom` from the call site and make sure that `Repr` is inferred to your concrete type `M[A]` by using collection traits that end on `Like` and have two type parameters

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.TraversableLike
import scala.language.higherKinds

def convert[M[x] <: TraversableLike[x, M[x]], A, B](
    in: M[A],
    f: A => B
)(implicit
  cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]]
 ): M[B] = in.map(f)(cbf)
```

Comment: I've got the same comment as @talex above: if `M[X]` extends `Traversable[X]` then it already supports `map` inherited from `TraversableLike`. So why just not `in.map(f)` ?

Comment: @AlexanderArendar static type of `Traversable[A].map(f: A => B)` is `Traversable[B]`, not the `M[B]` that author wants.

Comment: @Oleg Pyzhcov That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks! I tried passing `implicitly[CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]]]` to `in.map` but it didn't work

Comment: @DanielReigada yeah, your method doesn't know where to find one for `M[_]` until you supply it as an implicit parameter.